# Running again setInterval in jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, setinterval, countdowntimer

I want to run it again after the end of setInterval, but after running it in Ajax, it starts showing strange numbers. It is clear in the picture below.

When I run the page, setInterval works, but when the time expires and I make an ajax request, it doesn't start decrementing again.
Please help me.

All my code is.

```
const TIME_LIMIT = 10; // 10 second
let timePassed = 0;
let timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT;
let timerInterval = null; 

function onTimesUp() {
 clearInterval(timerInterval);
}

function startTimer() {
 timerInterval = setInterval(() => {
   timePassed = timePassed += 1;
   timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT - timePassed;
   document.getElementById("dividname").innerHTML = formatTime(
     timeLeft
   );
   if (timeLeft === 0) {
     onTimesUp();
   }
 }, 1000);
}
function formatTime(time) {
 const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
 let seconds = time % 60;
 if (seconds < 10) {
   seconds = `0${seconds}`;
 }
 return `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
}
```

And this is my Ajax code that sends the request and success is executed, but setInterval is not executed correctly. (I have put the picture below).

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: aw_ajax_url,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        'action': 'acttionname', 
    },
    success: function (data) { 
       onTimesUp();
       document.getElementById("dividname").text =  timeLeft;
       startTimer(); 
    } 
});
```

Image after restarting Ajax: It is sad

[image]

**Final note**: I want `setInterval to restart every time` I make an Ajax request. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Remove your php tag. There is no php in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to reset both timeLeft and timePassed. Also, setting innerText is unnecessary since it's already handled by the timer. It should be something like this:

```
success: function(data) { 
    onTimesUp();
    timePassed = 0;
    timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT;
    startTimer();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, my problem is solved
But I was asked why he didn't know the variable?
Even though I changed it from0 `const and let` to `var`, it still didn't recognize it. Do you know why?

Comment: @alexdev I don't get your question. Which variable is undefined / unrecognized by which part of the code?